# Seq sortWith function with strange behaviour

Tags: scala, sorting, exception

I was trying to sort elements of a Seq object with the sortWith function when I got an exception. I didn't use the sorted function because the code below is a simplification of the real code where the seq has tuples instead of ints.

See below that in the last two cases, when comparing with (v1 <= v2) an exception is thrown, but when comparing with (v1 < v2) no exception is thrown.

````
heitor@heitor-340XAA-350XAA-550XAA:~$ sbt console
[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.11)
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from sbt-updates.sbt ...
[info] loading global plugins from /home/heitor/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /home/heitor/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to example (in build file:/home/heitor/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.13.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.11).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val lst69 = List(1, 10, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
val lst69: List[Int] = List(1, 10, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

scala> lst69.size
val res0: Int = 69

scala> val lst68 = lst69.take(68)
val lst68: List[Int] = List(1, 10, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

scala> lst68.size
val res1: Int = 68

scala> lst68.sorted
val res2: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10)

scala> lst68.sortWith{ case (v1,v2) => (v1 <= v2) }
val res3: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10)

scala> lst69.sorted
val res4: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10)

scala> lst69.sortWith{ case (v1,v2) => (v1 <= v2) }
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
  at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:903)
  at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:520)
  at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:461)
  at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
  at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1441)
  at scala.collection.SeqOps.sorted(Seq.scala:700)
  at scala.collection.SeqOps.sorted$(Seq.scala:692)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.scala$collection$immutable$StrictOptimizedSeqOps$$super$sorted(List.scala:79)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StrictOptimizedSeqOps.sorted(StrictOptimizedSeqOps.scala:78)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StrictOptimizedSeqOps.sorted$(StrictOptimizedSeqOps.scala:78)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.sorted(List.scala:79)
  at scala.collection.SeqOps.sortWith(Seq.scala:727)
  at scala.collection.SeqOps.sortWith$(Seq.scala:727)
  at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.sortWith(Seq.scala:1161)
  ... 59 elided

scala> lst69.sortWith{ case (v1,v2) => (v1 < v2) }
val res6: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10)

scala> ```
````

Comment: Well `sortWith` expects a _"lower than"_, not a _"lower or equals than"_ comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead:

```
lst69.sortWith{ case (v1,v2) => (v1 < v2 || v1 == v2 ) }
```